# Wikimedia API: Why does this type of page break my image query?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to use the WikiMedia API for [this](https://japari-library.com) wiki, which say's that it's powered by MediaWiki. use the query:

```
action=query&format=json&prop=images
```

Usually, it gives me a list of the images on the page. But for a specific type of page, it doesn't give me images that are clearly on the page. For example:

```
action=query&format=json&prop=images&titles=Serval
```

the [result](https://japari-library.com/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=images&titles=Serval) contains the images on the [page](https://japari-library.com/wiki/Serval), notably `ServalOriginal.jpg`. But in this query:

```
action=query&format=json&prop=images&titles=Serval/Nexon Game
```

the [result](https://japari-library.com/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=images&titles=Serval/Nexon%20Game) does not contain the important image `ServalOriginal.jpg`, even though it's featured on the [page](https://japari-library.com/wiki/Serval/Nexon_Game). However, in the similar query:

```
action=query&format=json&prop=images&titles=Serval/Anime
```

the [result](https://japari-library.com/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=images&titles=Serval/Anime) does contain the image in the same place, `ServalAnime.jpg`, which makes sense given the [page](https://japari-library.com/wiki/Serval/Anime).

This appears all over the wiki, but I can't find documentation that would make me expect this result. Why is it doing this, and how can I work around it so that I can get the images I need from all the pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the images prop only returns the first 10 images. To get all available images on a page (maximum 500) use the `imlimit` property, like this:

https://japari-library.com/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=images&imlimit=500&titles=Serval/Nexon%20Game